# How to remove the (1) from filenames using the find command

Tags: shell, find, osx, regular-expression, rename

I recently converted all of my FLAC files to a lower sampling rate of 44.1 kHz and bit depth of 24 bits (because iPhone/iPod don't support anything above that) using XLD on my Mac OS 10.7 (Lion).

Although I told XLD to overwrote all previous files, XLD appended a `(1)` at the end of very file like from

```
some_song.m4a
```

to

```
some_song(1).m4a
```

So now I want to remove that `(1)` from all the FLAC files I converted.

I know I could have probably used some program or even an AppleScript to rename the files, but I wanted to learn using the old school way of command line.

I know that `find . -name *\(1\).m4a` will grab all the converted FLAC file.

Next I know I have to do something with `-exec` and `mv` to rename all the found files. But what I can't figure out is how to keep the original filename and only remove the `(1)`.

Maybe I need to do some group regex capturing to store the part of the filename that I don't want to modify? Or maybe it's not possible to do everything in one line and I should create a shell script (which I'm not that comfortable doing, but I'm willing to give it a try).

Any tips or suggestions are welcomed! Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote? It seems like a valid question...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't try to parse `find` output except as a last resort.  It is important to realize that on Unix file systems, file names are not strings (a common misconception) but rather *binary blobs* which can contain any character except `/` and the null character.  Parsing file names safely and correctly is enough of a pain that 99% of the time you'll just want to avoid doing it altogether (just look at how hairy the `sed` expression in [@yarek's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38455/9537) is and even that doesn't cover all cases).  Thankfully, in this case there is a much simpler approach:

```
find . -name '*(1).m4a' -execdir sh -c \
'for arg; do mv "$arg" "${arg%(1).m4a}".m4a; done' _ {} \+
```

Comment: neat approach yet as hairy as the sed expression :) +1

Comment: something's missing here... where's `done`?

Comment: @yarek Thanks for the catch.  The biggest difference between this and the `sed` pipe approach is this is much safer.  It's still easier to read than regex backslash soup, provided you understand some basic shell scripting constructs.

Comment: You're right; this is much cleaner. And the `$arg` variable makes it much easier to read.

Comment: For those of us trying to get better at our understanding of 'basic shell scripting constructs', can you briefly describe in words what this is doing?

Comment: @DQdlM The snippet I posted above is just `find` invoking `sh` with fairly portable POSIX syntax.  For more details, you can check out the [section on Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), the [section on compound commands that explains the `for` loop](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04), and the [POSIX `find` spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).  In addition to those resources, I'd be happy to answer any *specific* questions you have.

Comment: @jw013 thanks for the additional info, that helps a lot.

Comment: I tried this command right now and I realized it doesn't work since it doesn't include the folder path leading up to the filename. So `mv` will complain and say `No such file or directory`.

Comment: @hobbes3 Are you sure?  There shouldn't be any folder paths in the `mv` command since `-execdir` is used.  Compare the output of `find -exec pwd \;` and `find -execdir pwd \;`.  How are you running it?

Comment: I'm running this command on Mac OS X. So that's probably what's causing it to fail.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.  Do you have the exact command and error message?  Try using `sh -xc` instead of `sh -c` for extra information.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It would say `+ for arg in '"$@"'` `+ mv 'song(1).mp3' 'song.mp3'` `mv: rename song(1).mp3 to song.mp3: No such file or directory`. The thing is `song(1).mp3` is not in the current directory; it's one folder deep.

Comment: @hobbes3 I'm wondering if `-execdir` is working as it should.  Try inserting a `pwd;` right before the `for arg` to see what directory the `mv` is being run in.

Comment: @jw013 The `pwd` inside the script is showing the directory where I run the `find` command, ie `/Users/hobbes3/Music`. The music files are actually in `/Users/hobbes3/Music/folder/song(1).mp3` and `/Users/hobbes3/Music/folder/folder/song2(1).mp3`. `find . -name '*(1).mp3'` gives `./folder/song(1).mp3` `./folder/folder/song2(1).mp3`.

Comment: @hobbes That's odd.  As another test to make sure `sh` isn't doing anything funny, try replacing the entire `sh -c '...'` part with `pwd` and see if you get the same thing as your previous run with `pwd` inside the `'...'`.

Answer (score 6):

On Debian and Ubuntu, I can use `rename 's/\(1\)//' *.m4a` to solve your problem.

Comment: Weird, I can do `man rename`, but I actually don't have `rename`: `-bash: rename: command not found` (`which rename` doesn't show anything).

Comment: @hobbes3 on the mac here `man -a rename` finds *rename* (2) - the syscall, and *rename* (n) - the TCL command. There are neither *rename* (1) nor the utility itself there.

Comment: IIRC, `rename` is a perl script included with the examples included in some perl installs, and a couple distros include it in the path because it's a convenient command. (@Hobbes perhaps you can find it on the internet)

Comment: @Kevin on my system `rename` is normal binary (not perl). However another caveat is that not all versions of `rename` support regexes. The version I have for example only lets you do direct string replacements, eg `rename '(1)' '' *.m4a`

Comment: The Perl `rename` script is only installed by Debian and derivatives. Other Linux systems have a different `rename` utility (shown by Patrick). OSX has neither.

Answer (score 4):

In zsh, using [zmv](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/zshcontrib.1.html):

```
autoload zmv      # you can put this line in your .zshrc
zmv '(*)\(1\)(*)' '$1$2'
```

In the second argument (the new name), `$1` and `$2` refer to the parenthesized groups `(PATTERN)` in the source pattern. Another way of writing this renaming is

```
zmv '(*)' '${1/\(1\)/}'
```

Answer (score 3):

The following approach gives you ability to preview/prune the generated commands *before* executing them, and it is very portable: it should work not only on a mac, not only with bash, and not only with GNU sed; even on systems without `find`(1) command it is possible to substitute it with `du`(1) without a trouble.

```
find . -name '*(1).m4a' |
sed 's/\(.*\)(1).m4a$/mv & \1.m4a/'
```

If happy with the printed commands, re-run with `| sh -x` appended.

If concerned about spaces in file names, add another *s* to escape all spaces:

```
find . -name '*(1).m4a' |
sed -e 's/ /\\ /g' -e 's/\(.*\)(1).m4a$/mv & \1.m4a/'
```

If other special chars are expected, it gets a litle bit more tricky:

```
find . -name '*(1).m4a' |
sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g" -e 's/\(.*\)(1).m4a$/mv '\''&'\'' '\''\1.m4a'\'/
```

First function converts all `'` into a form such that these are taken literally when in the middle of `'...'`-escaped string. Second function generates *mv* commands whose arguments are enclosed within `'...'`.

Comment: That command isn't escaping the filename (the spaces, `(`, and all other special characters) or adding quotes around the filename. I tried modifying your command, but I couldn't figure out how to add quotes around both filenames for the `mv` command. One of the resulting output from your command is `mv ./The Beatles - Let It Be (MFSL LP 1-109) 24-96 Vinyl Rip/01 Two Of Us(1).m4a ./The Beatles - Let It Be (MFSL LP 1-109) 24-96 Vinyl Rip/01 Two Of Us.m4a`. And if I run that command I get `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`.

Comment: this is supposed to be a homework :) but ok, i'll update the answer

Comment: By the way GNU sed can execute command itself by adding `e` command after substitution. For example `find . -name '*(1).m4a' | sed 's/\(.*\)(1).m4a$/mv & \1.m4a/e'` will exexcute command without piping to `sh -x`.

Comment: @Rush that's the only sed which does that; and it needs to start the shell anyway, but a new one for each command (reminds the *make's* problem, doesn't it?)

Comment: @yarek Thanks! It worked! I think I understand most of the third command (because I worked with search and replace function `s/` and regex in VIM, but I'm really confused about the \\\\ you have in the first function.

Comment: @yarek actually there is way to execute all commands in one shell with sed: ` find . -name '*(1).m4a' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\\(\\([^\n]*\\)(1).m4a\\)\n*/mv \1 \2.m4a;/ge'` . Though it is pretty dirty hack and in general you're right =)

Comment: @hobbes3 \\\\ is flattened to \\ by shell while removing double-quotes; \\ makes \ a literal part of the regexp.

Comment: @Rush yet it is much simpler to pipe to shell - that's a fact

Comment: And, yes: it shall work not only on mac, not only with bash, and not only with GNU sed.

Comment: I don't think we should be downvoting. It is a valid solution after all.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small script that does it:

```
for var in `find . -type f -name "*(1).m4a"`; do
    new=`echo $var | cut -d'(' -f1`;
    mv $var $new.m4a;
done
```

Comment: this one will choke on files with spaces in their names; also it requires big enough temporary storage for the `\`find ...\``